# convert datetime type to tuple in python

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion, tuples, timedelta

Is there any one liner method to convert datetime to simple tuple

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> new_date = datetime. today() + timedelta(12)
>>> new_date
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 26, 13, 31, 36, 838650)
```

How do I convert new_date to tuple type.

This is what I have tried

```
tuple(new_date)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    tuple(new_date)
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable
```

**Expected output :**

```
>> (2020, 5, 26, 13, 31, 36, 838650)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "customize" the output (e.g. including microseconds), you could use attrgetter from the operator module to get the attributes from the datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime
from operator import attrgetter

attrs = ('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond')

d = datetime.now()
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 12, 49, 35, 33067)

d_tuple = attrgetter(*attrs)(d)
# (2020, 5, 14, 12, 49, 35, 33067)
```

Otherwise, just use the `timetuple()` as shown in the other answers (probably more efficient if you can live without microseconds).

Answer (score 2):

There is a `timetuple` you can use.

```
>>> new_date.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=26, tm_hour=11, tm_min=15, tm_sec=30, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=147, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> tuple(new_date.timetuple())
(2020, 5, 26, 11, 15, 30, 1, 147, -1)
```

You do not actually need to convert it to a tuple, the above is just to make a point. You can use it where you use a normal tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use `timetuple()` or `utctimetuple()` for the conversion:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 14, 17, 18, 39, 958430)
>>> dt.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2020, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=17, tm_min=18, tm_sec=39, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=135, tm_isdst=-1)
>>>
```